# Java variable passing from method - a deck draw program

Tags: java

The method of a class to draw a random card from a deck and prevent repeat draws is failing to do so because the iteration value is not carrying over from the method consistently.  Is it possible to prevent the variables from a method from being destroyed?

Here is the class and method that I'm using for the deck draw portion of the code:

```
public class Deck
{
   // Array for the deck of cards
   private String[] DeckOfCards =
   { " 2 of spades ", " 3 of spades ", " 4 of spades ", " 5 of spades ", " 6 of spades ", " 7 of spades        
     ", " 8 of spades ", " 9 of spades ", " 10 of spades ", " Jack of spades ", " Queen of spades ",
     " King of Spades ", " Ace of spades ", " 2 of clubs ", " 3 of clubs ", " 4 of clubs ", " 5 of        
     clubs ", " 6 of clubs ", " 7 of clubs ", " 8 of clubs ", " 9 of clubs ", " 10 of clubs ", 
     " Jack of clubs ", " Queen of clubs ", " King of Clubs ", " Ace of clubs ", " 2 of diamonds ",
     " 3 of diamonds ", " 4 of diamonds ", " 5 of diamonds ", " 6 of diamonds ", " 7 of diamonds ",
     " 8 of diamonds ", " 9 of diamonds ", " 10 of diamonds ", " Jack of diamonds ", 
     " Queen of     diamonds ", " King of Diamonds ", " Ace of diamonds ", " 2 of hearts ", 
     " 3 of hearts ", " 4 of hearts ", " 5 of hearts ", " 6 of hearts ", " 7 of hearts ",
     " 8 of hearts ", " 9 of hearts ", " 10 of hearts ", " Jack of hearts ", " Queen of hearts ",
     " King of Hearts ", " Ace of hearts " };

   // Declaring other variables
   int[] alreadyDrawnCards = new int[53];
   int drawnCard;
   int i = 0;
   int j = 0;

   /**
    *  method used to draw cards
    */
   protected int draw()
   {      
  
      drawnCard = (int)(Math.random() * 53);
  
      while(j < i)
      {
         if(drawnCard == alreadyDrawnCards[j])
         {
        
            drawnCard = (int)(Math.random() * 53);
            j = -1;         
         }
     
         j++;
      }
  
      if(i < 53) 
      {
         alreadyDrawnCards[i] = drawnCard; // add drawn card to drawn cards
         i++;
      }
  
      System.out.println("The" + DeckOfCards[drawnCard] + "was drawn from the deck");
  
      return drawnCard;
   }
}
```

The code for the invocation of the method is:

```
public class BlackjackGameSimulator
{

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Deck BlackJackDeck = new Deck();
      BlackJackDeck.draw();

   }
}
```

Comment: `the iteration value is not carrying over from the method consistently` What exactly does that mean? `Is it possible to prevent the variables from a method from being destroyed?` Again, what exactly does that mean? Variables vanish when their scope ends.

Comment: Rest `j` back to `0` when calling `draw` - or better yet, making a local variable

Comment: BTW Java's `Collections` class provides a `shuffle()` method that basically does this for you.  Just shuffle your deck after putting it into a `List`, then use `remove()` to pull out one card at a time.  Doesn't matter which card, after a shuffle the order will be random.

Comment: You variables are already instance variables - so their values will persist between method calls. The porblem is you are not reseting `j` variable between call by setting it to 0. I dont think `j` needs to be an instance variable.

Comment: How to draw n random cards (which you have implemented as Strings): `List<String> cards = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(DeckOfCards)); Collections.shuffle(cards); List<String> hand = cards.subList(0, n);`

Comment: @tkausl I mean that I want the i value saved after running the method and carrying over the next time I run the method.   I understand the trash collector destroys it if there is no reference to it (i.e. when the method ends) so it is eventually destroyed, but I am not sure how to save the iteration and carry it over to every instance of the method 'draw' being run.

Comment: I'd go with the suggestion in the comment from Bohemian. Shuffle the deck in the `Deck` constructor.  When a card is drawn, remove it from the head (or tail) of the list. You could, instead, have a `nextCard` counter that indexes the `List` and gets incremented when a card is drawn.

Answer (score 0):

First, ensure that you initialize your "alreadyDrawnCards" array with "-1" values using an **instance initializer block**. This is important because when an array of ints is instantiated in Java, it will always have a card with a value of "0" in java:

```
{
    Arrays.fill(alreadyDrawnCards, -1);
}
```

Next, let's fix the code to correctly search for duplicates in the array. This is a brute-force approach, but let's focus on correctness before optimizing for performance:

```
for (var j = 0; j < alreadyDrawnCards.length; j++) {
        var alreadyDrawnCard = alreadyDrawnCards[j];
        if (drawnCard == alreadyDrawnCard) {
            drawnCard = (int) (Math.random() * 52);
            j = 0;
        }
    }
```

Additionally, there's no need to check if i < 53 here because you'll encounter an exception regardless. Instead, you can add the following code at the beginning of your draw method to handle an empty deck gracefully::

```
if(i == 52){
        throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("Deck is empty");
    }
```

This ensures that your code correctly handles the case when the deck is empty.

Hope it helps.

Comment: definitely does, thank you.